# Terraform Intermittent error on Apple's M1

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, apple-m1

When I run `terraform plan`, I expect to see a plan but instead I get

```bash
│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: failed to
│ instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message:
│
│ This usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
│ needs to be recompiled to support the latest protocol...
```

System is: arm64 m1 - Monterey - TFEnv - Terraform 1.1.9

Answer (score 10):

### Solution

#### Explanation

1. An issue in Go runtime running amd64 M1 through Apple's Rosetta
2. [TFenv](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv) installed the amd64 version of Terraform instead of arm64.

#### Patch

Set the variable `GODEBUG=asyncpreemptoff=1` by prepending it to the front of your terraform or adding it to your bash profile.

#### Fix

Make sure you are running the right build for your system.

```bash
➜ terraform version
Terraform v1.1.9
on darwin_arm64
```

If you are on an M1 and see `darwin_amd64` when you run `terraform version`, try installing Terraform again.

With TFenv

```
TFENV_ARCH=arm64 tfenv install 1.2.4
tfenv use 1.2.4
```

#### Details

1. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23850
2. https://yaleman.org/post/2021/2021-01-01-apple-m1-terraform-and-golang/

Comment: Cheers! specifying the TFENV_ARCH flag fixed it for me on my M1 Mac Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the env var `TFENV_ARCH` to arm64 and re-install Terraform again using `tfenv`